# Launch same application with different .desktop (and icons) task manager

Tags: application, .desktop, dock

Suppose  I have a program `myapp`. It has two sub tasks, A and B. Launcjhing `myapp --task A` launches A and similar for B. Launching `myapp` only opens another intro window. I have three .desktop files in `/usr/local/share/applications`: `myapp.desktop`, `myappA.desktop` and `myappB.desktop`; all with different icons. When I launch `myappA` from applications menu in my desktop environment, it opens task A but the icon shown in plasma task manager (or dock in gnome) is of `myapp.desktop`. Also if I run `myappA` and `myappB` together, they are grouped together (I can prevent grouping but that will not group two task A windows also). The behavior is consistent in KDE, GNOME and other DE's.

So is there any way to have three different icons for task A, task B and intro windows in task manager?

Comment: Firefox does support specifying WM class. Not all apps support this.

Comment: Apparently as per free desktop specification grouping depends on WM_CLASS and there is no way to force it unless the app allows. A workaround might be to add a hook with startup notify to change WM_CLASS property with `xprop(1)`.

Comment: Did you get any solution for that?